# How to avoid multiple node queries?

Tags: react-router, relayjs, react-router-relay

I have 3 pages (components using `react-router-relay`) in my app, `ProductList`, `ProductDetail` and `BrandList`.

To illustrate the problem, let me walk through the flow and leave the code at the bottom.

- First I go to `ProductList` and see the list of products, each with brand's name. It works as expected.
- Then I click on one of the product, this will render `ProductDetail`. Everything still works as expected.
- Now when I go to `BrandList`, the problem is Relay sends multiple `node(id: $id_0)` queries to server.

What happen is Relay's store has already fetched `brands` after step 2 in `ProductDetail`. And in step 3, `BrandList` asks for more fields than Relay's store currently has. So Relay sends multiple `node` queries, 30 queries as I have 30 brands, however this is inefficient and noticeably slow.

I can fix this by **asking the same fields** in both `ProductDetail` ([A]) and `BrandList` ([B]) (please see queries below). However, it means `ProductDetail` gets unnecessary fields that it doesn't use.

I'm not sure if I've missed something very obvious here or there is a better way to avoid multiple node queries in this case. It would be arguably better if I could tell Relay to re-fetch `brands` entirely in step 3 above when Relay has partial data already in store and going to send `node` queries to get more fields.

// The relevant queries for each component. Please note the comments on [A] and [B] below

`ProductList`

```
export default Relay.createContainer(ProductList, {
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer {
        id
        products(first: 1000) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              localId
              name
              brand {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  },
})
```

`ProductDetail`

```
export default Relay.createContainer(ProductDetail, {
  fragments: {
    product: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Perfume {
        id
        localId
        name
        brand {
          name
        }
      }
    `,
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer {
        id
        brands(first: 1000) {
          edges {
            node {
              localId
              name      // <------ [A] ask only name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  },
})
```

`BrandList`

```
export default Relay.createContainer(BrandList, {
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer {
        id
        brands(first: 1000) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              localId
              name
              slug        // <----- [B] ask more fields than [A]
              country     // <----- [B] ask more fields than [A]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  },
})
```